# How do I find the HTML/CSS/JavaScript files that Shiny ultimately outputs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, file, shiny

From my understanding, everything on the internet being rendered in my web browser is some combination of HTML, CSS, and/or JavaScript. Shiny apps can be rendered in web browsers.

By my logic, this means that when my Shiny app runs, it must ultimately produce some combination of HTML, CSS, and/or JavaScript files.

I've written `ui.R`, `server.R`, and `global.R`. My question then is, how can I access the HTML/CSS/JavaScript files directly?

Answer (score 1):

After reading through the [How to build a Shiny app](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/build.html) page, it looks like Shiny renders the output (HTML, CSS, etc.) when it runs, so the interface you see is created dynamically, rather than stored as a static page.

This would be akin to how some web servers use PHP (or another server-side language) to render the HTML that the user sees; the HTML is shown in the browser, but there is no static `index.html` page, for example, with its own URL.

If your Shiny app opens in your browser, then you should be able to right click on the page and select **View Source** (or a similar option, depending on your browser) to view the generated HTML, CSS, or JavaScript.